# Login screen background wallpaper not changing with Dfcon-editor nor Ubuntu Tweak [Ubuntu 14.04]

Tags: 14.04, login-screen, desktop-background, dconf, ubuntu-tweak

I am trying to set a new background image for my log in but I can't.
I tried configuring via Dconf-editor with root mode but every time I set the new image and set to `True` the `draw-user-backgrounds` and then reboot to take effect the only result I get is the background filled with a solid purple background without the logon of "Ubuntu 14.04", with the propertie `draw-user-backgrounds` set to `False` (unticked).
I also have tried via Ubuntu Tweak but I was not successful, even trying some posts saying that I would need set the permissions for others to `read-only` and changing the owner of the file to root.

What I need to do?
The file I am trying to use is a `.jpg` and it is in the folder `/usr/share/backgrounds`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with 14.04 since I recently did a dist-upgrade. Also after logging in, the upper part of the blank purple screen becomes garbled & fills up with thin black & white rectangles. Slower boot time too.

Acer laptop with intel graphics card.

Later.

I tried all the things the OP had done but I solved my problem by changing the login screen background back to the default. For some reason the login screen didn't like my current wallpaper. It was only a jpg of about 500k, so it's not as if it were a strain, but there you are.